# Duda general BBDD SQLLite en aplicaciones móviles

Tags: android, sql, ios, app, sqllite

Tengo una duda bastante general de **cómo funciona la BBDD SqlLite** aplicada a las APPs de IOS o de Android.

Cuando yo trabajo con una aplicación web por ejemplo, la bbdd está alojada en un servidor, pero en una app de ios o de android, cuando usamos la bbdd SqlLite.

¿Dónde debemos alojarla para usarla desde varios dispositivos?

He leído que la BBDD SqlLite genera un archivo **.db**, pero este fichero, ¿Es local al dispositivo?

Comment: sqlite trabaja de forma local y es bastante engorroso, si quieres sincronización con servidor y local tienes la solución de Google firebase, ademas las herramientas firebase tambien tienes autentificación de usuarios, envio de mensajes push, almacenamiento por cada usuario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlLite es una BD solo local. Es una base de datos Open Source, es muy popular en muchos dispositivos pequeños, como Android.

*Las ventajas que presenta utilizar SQLite es que no requiere configuración, no tiene un servidor de base de datos ejecutándose en un proceso separado y es relativamente simple su empleo.*

La base de datos de cada aplicación se ubica en la siguiente ruta dentro del dispositivo: `/data/data/[mi.paquete.app]/databases/`

En donde **[mi.paquete.app]** es el nombre del paquete principal de nuestra aplicación Android. En dicho directorio se almacena el archivo de la base de datos en sí, que posee el nombre especificado en el constructor de la clase `SQLiteOpenHelper`. También puede contener el “**rollback journal**” de la base de datos, que posee el mismo nombre, pero añadiendo el prefijo “-**journal**”. Por ejemplo, si la base de datos se llama ***“BDPrueba.db”***, entonces los archivos que encontraremos serían ***“BDPrueba.db”***, y posiblemente ***“BDPrueba.db-Journal”***

Si deseas que tu app se comunique con múltiples usuarios vía Internet (TCP/IP), un **WebService** es la solución.

*Nota: si deseas implementar con un WebService puedes usar el motor de base de datos de Google, que es Firebase para trabajar ***localmente/servidor*** y sincronización de datos entre varios dispositivos ([Click aquí para saber mas](https://firebase.google.com/)), pero este motor es no sql, es decir esta formado por nodos, no por un "relacional entre tablas", o las mas convencionales como; MySql, SqlServer, etc.*

Comment: Tambien existe la solución de Google (Firebase) para trabajar localmente/servidor y sincronización de datos entre varios dispositivos, si encuentras apropiado puedes expandir tu respuesta https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: @Webserveis gracias por la sugerencia, nunca esta demás un aporte :D

Comment: @AshleyG.Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Yayo un agrado haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite como su nombre indica, es un motor de base de datos reducido, que trabaja sobre la máquina host, por lo tanto el archivo de la base de datos se almacena en algún lugar de tu dispositivo. Si puedes trabajar en modo compartido lo desconozco, pero no creo que sea la mejor forma.
**Si tienes pensado usar una base de datos común** a otros dispositivos no tiene sentido que uses Sqllite, para eso tienes la opción de webapi y los motores de base de datos mas comunes.

Sqlite tiene una forma particular de crear la base de datos, las tablas y acceder a los regitros, que debes consultar según la plataforma desde donde uses sqlite.

Puedes revisar [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810430/get-database-path) para ver cómo obtener la ruta del archivo de tu base de datos Sqlite y algo más de información

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!